# Create a pickerInput with choices and subchoices based on dataframe columns

Tags: r, shinywidgets, pickerinput

I have the dataframe below and I want to create a `pickerInput()` with `Dimension` as the main choices and `Subdimension` as sub-choices like:

```
pickerInput(
    inputId = "p1",
    label = "Select all option",
    choices = list(Environmental = list("A","B","C"),
                   EnvironmentalB = list("A"),
                   EnvironmentalC = list("A","B")),
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
  )
```

In this dataframe I have only `Environmental` but they may be more

```
df<-structure(list(Dimension = c("environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
"environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental"
), Subdimension = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the list / sublist using `split`:

```
pickerInput(
  inputId = "p1",
  label = "Select all option",
  choices = split(unique(df)$Subdimension,unique(df)$Dimension),
  multiple = TRUE,
  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
)
```

[image]

Comment: for some reason instead of taking subchoices as ubique I get each one multiple times

Comment: Do you get the issue on the example dataset you provided or on another dataset?

Comment: split(unique(df$Subdimension) and split(unique(df$Dimension) instead

Comment: as I can understand now you cannot click on the Dimension only on the subdimensions right?

Comment: You might be able to click on the dimension if there's only one subdimension : in this case, `PickerInput` doesn't show the subdimension